# Remove red error lines in VS code for TWIG

Tags: templating, vscode

I've come across this a few times in my code / and others.

Basically - there is no error, this is valid syntax and works, but is there a way I can highlight this and tell VS code - this is ok, dont display the error for this one specific section.

CODE:

```
{% if imgE.focalPoint|length %}
          style="object-position: 
          {# Set X #}{{ imgE.focalPoint | first * 100 ~ '% ' }}{# Set Y #}{{ imgE.focalPoint | last * 100 ~ '%' }};"
          {% endif %}
          />
```

Obviously I really don't want to disable error highlighting, but I also do not want to have this eye sore which might also distract me from a real error.

any suggestions?

Thank!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what extension you're using for the Twig syntax highlighting and which language the file is set to use in VS Code.

#### Extensions

I use [Twig Language 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2) – this extension can handle the code you posted without errors. It also comes with snippets, formatting and everything you need to work with Twig and Craft.

I can reproduce this error only with [Twig Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language) (version 1), this one doesn't seem great at handling CSS / JS inside Twig files.

Make sure you have only one extension for Twig files installed, since having multiple plugins for syntax highlighting for the same language can lead to problems. I would use Twig Language 2 and uninstall all other plugins.

#### Language configuration

Make sure the file is configured to use the correct language. For Twig Language 2, it should say `HTML (Twig)` on the right of the bar at the bottom. If it shows the wrong language, press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, then <kbd>m</kbd> to bring up the language menu and select the right language.

You can also change the associated language for `*.twig` files in the settings (search for `files.associations`).

Comment: So that did remove the error lines - but has also created another issue - now I have lost the HTML inteliesense which makes it was easier to write html faster.... any suggestions for keeping HTML while using the TWIG 2 plugin? Thanks for you help :)

Comment: @Wally You mean the autocomplete / snippet expansion for HTML? That's provided by [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet). By default, it's not active in Twig files, you need to change your settings as mentioned in the README for the [Twig Language 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2) plugin.

Comment: Yeah that solved it thank you - For future uses - VS code command pallet > Settings > Extensions > Emmet > Include Languages - add twig and html